# How to validate format string

Tags: .net, internationalization, string.format

We have lots of strings in our resource files that contains format .e.g

> “{0} has moved to {1}”

These strings are passed to *String.Format()* by the applications, sometimes the translators mess up the “formatting markers”   Therefore I wish to find/write a tool that checks that all strings in the resource file has a valid format.

I know for each key the numbers of args that are passed to String.Format so that can feed into the validations as well.

So apart from checking that the “{“ match the “}” is there a easy way to find most errors in the format strings?

(I am using .NET, this checking will of course be done as part of the build process)

Comment: Make sure not to miss escaped curly brackets, such as `"this is a format: {0}, this is not: {{text}}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with a simple solution that gives a reasonable result, I know the number of argument to the format statement but not the type of the arguments.   However most arguments are strings.

So

```
if (numberOfArguments == 3)
{
  try
  {
    String.Format(theTranslatorString, "", "", "")
  }
  catch
  {
     // tell the translator there is a problem with the string format
  }
}
```

Of course this would be written without an “if” for each number of arguments in real life.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a classic unit-test scenario. Can you drive an automated build/unit-test off the source-code commit trigger for these ? The unit test would simply check that each format string is still parse-able.

Comment: Just what I am thinking of, but how to I "check that each format string is still parse-able."

Comment: Won't it throw an exception if it can't parse it ? Or perhaps you can check after formatting that the string contains the elements you expect. e.g. try to insert -TEST1-, -TEST2- or similar...

Comment: I wish to have a unit test that checks the foramt of ALL the translated strings.  We don't have unit tests for most of our UI and most of the translatable strings are used in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you validate a string in expression,so you should use **Regular Expressions**
Look at [link text](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)