# Resources and localization - parent / child strings in .resx files?

Tags: string, parent-child, resx

I'm creating WebResources.resx file with several string messages I'd like to categorize:

Signup_Status_Inactive
Signup_Status_Reserved
etc...

Since it's just an XML file in the background, is it possible to create parent/child relationships so I don't have to prefix related strings and follow a better dot notation?

To get around this I can create a class with some properties accessed through proper dot notation, ie StatusMessages.Signup.Inactive - but that's just extra work.

Is there only one level to the string component of the .resx files?

Additionally, how do you output session variables as a part of the resx value - ie: 
"Your Card #**" + HttpContext.Current.Session["ReservedCardNum"] + "** has been reserved for you."

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All the keys in a .resx file are single level**, however there is nothing stopping you from using your own XML format, provided you write the code to read it and any tools that are needed to maintain it.

---

To output session variables,  I would use String.Format()

Normally you would write

```
String.Format(“"Your Card #{0}  has been reserved for you.", 
              HttpContext.Current.Session["ReservedCardNum"])
```

So just instead just use

```
String.Format(stringLookedFromResouceFile, 
              HttpContext.Current.Session["ReservedCardNum"])
```

And put the “{0}” in the translated string, that way the translators can change the order of the words if needed.

---

Think about how you will communicate to the translators what the placeholders,  If the translators are using a resource editor that shows the comment field, you could add comments like “{0} = username”

You will also have to somehow check that the translators don’t mess up the place holders, I have seen translators change “{0}” to “(0)” as they “think the other sort of brackets look better” etc!  or delete one of the brackens so the string format is no longer valid.

see [How to validate format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277288/how-to-validate-format-string)

Comment: +1. Also if using the resource editor use the Comments field to document what is going into each of the replacement fields; context (such as "personal name" or "item count"), and data type are really useful for translators.